# Linkedin API. How can I retrieve impressions from a video ugcPost

Tags: linkedin-api

I have been able to retrieve the video statistics from the company page ( in which I am an administrator). However when I get the statistics ( likes, impressions, engagement, etc.) from all the company's shares/posts the fields for the video posts appear to not exist. Hope you cna help me, here is the request I've been using:

'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=organizationURN&shares=List(shareURN)

*I've tried input of the ugcPost URN in the shareURN field but still no result yet.

Thanks in advance!